# Deny list and Allow list for Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-application-firewall

I have an Azure Web app running behind the Azure Application gateway which is configured in WAF mode. I have allowed only Azure Gateway IP and our own public/proxy IP to connect Azure Wab App which means all traffic is being routed to Web is being through Application Gateway only.

Now, I want to DENY access to specific list of IPs to my Azure Web App. I am not sure how and where can i configure this DENY list ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I want to DENY access to specific list of IPs to my Azure Web
>   App.

Based on my knowledge, maybe you can use `IP Restrictions` to **allow** some IP to access your app.

More information about **IP Restrictions**, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions).

---

**Update:**

Thanks for Saurabh Singh share, customer can edit `web.config` to add IP list:

```
     <security>     
       <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true"> 
        <add ipAddress="111.223.118.66" allowed="false"/>
     </ipSecurity>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response Jason. I have reviewed this article but this is about setting up the "Allow List" which I have already configured on Azure web app so that only my gateway can access the web app But WAF is open for everyone on pot 80/443. This is where I want to block certain IPs. I am not sure of Azure Application Gateway have this capability or not.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh For now, there is no firewall settings for Azure Application gateway.

Comment: ok Jason, does that means i can NOT achieve my scenario ? It could be something at Azure web app level?

Comment: @SaurabhSingh Azure web app only can add allow IP list, application gateway communicate web app use Azure private IP address. Maybe you can set https for application gateway.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh Based on my knowledge, application gateway can map port to another port, so I think you can expose different port to the Internet:)

Comment: @SaurabhSingh Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: hey Jason, thanks for the help here, i found the fix here we had to update the we.b.config file with following code to DENY any IP.ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true"> 
            <clear/> 
             <add ipAddress="111.223.118.66" allowed="false"/>
   </ipSecurity>

Comment: @SaurabhSingh thank you for your share, I will update it to my answer.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh I have update my answer, please check it, thanks again:)